# Culture is not getting updaet in UI

Tags: c#, silverlight

I tried to implement localization in SIlverlight.

I follow this link for it

http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2009/08/26/silverlight-string-localization.aspx

Now the problem is that when i am hard coding culture like this

```
  <object>
   ...
  <param name="uiculture" value="ar-SA" />
  <param name="culture" value="ar-SA" />
 </object>
```

it is working fine but when i am trying to change the culture by changing combobox value it is not getting update the UI

```
<param name="uiculture" value="<%= System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture %>" />
<param name="culture" value="<%= System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture %>" />
```

Can any body let me know please why it is not updating the UI ..

Comment: Can you please explain what is not working for you in bit more detail?

Comment: There is a known issue with Silverlight combobox with selected value binding. May be this link will help you [http://forums.lhotka.net/forums/p/9786/45971.aspx](http://forums.lhotka.net/forums/p/9786/45971.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

In order the Culture to change, you need that the silverlight application will be reloaded,
and for this to happen you need the page containing the silverlight application will be refreshed. which means you will need to do a postback to the server.

What we did in our application is to "navigate" to the page with QueryString that contains the selected languague.

the code to create a refresh is as follows:

```
HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(New Uri(App.Current.Host.Source, "../MainPage.aspx" + "?" + l_newCulture))
```

In the server side you need to update a session variable or something and then use the code you mentioned above, but only instead of the `System.Threading.Thread.Current..`, use a property that wraps up the session variable, so in the page it will look like this:

```
<param name="uiculture" value="<%= SelectedCurrentUICulture %>" />
<param name="culture" value="<%= SelectedCurrentCulture %>"
```

Good Luck
Lior